# how to update portable software one every production pc client

Tags: windows, version-control, active-directory, portable-applications

So we have many production PC inputting data for Manufacturing Process in the production line, in each of these clients we already have portable applications in disk D for running this application, occasionally we receive some updates for this portable application so that the portable version change to a higher version. The problem is every time we received the update, we need to manually replace the application on each of this client one by one,

my question is, is there any way to make this process automatically without manually replacing the application one by one onsite?

each of this client is already connected with the AD Server. Already research for using git VCS but when using git we need to pull resources from client manually.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible with **Configuration Management tool (Pushed Based Type)** i.e., **Ansible**. You can build an infrastructure as a code on a server that server can help to push the updated version of software to all the production PC which should connected to same server.

Ansible is an open-source IT configuration management, Deployment orchestration tool. It aims to provide large productivity gain to a wide variety of automation challenges.

Please follow this link to get this apply : https://opensource.com/article/20/9/install-packages-ansible